# How to Obtain an Accurate Location Provider

Tags: android, gps, location

When I used the code bellow in my phone it always selects the network to get Longitude and Latitude and didn't select the GPS even when the Wi-Fi is off. I want the application to choose the best, running, accurate location provider.

```
   LocationManager LM1=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider=LM1.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    LM1.requestLocationUpdates(provider,500,1,this);
    ET3.setText(provider);
```

the permissions used are:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>    
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the most accurate, check if GPS is enabled.  If it is, use it.  If not, use network.  Sending a blank criteria to getBestProvider will never cause you to use GPS-  its going to assume you don't need that accuracy.

Comment: thank you for you info, but (why and how) when the wi_fi is off and GPS is off it still get location from network. please i want to understand im confused. please give me answer. thanx again

Comment: It uses the 3G/4G signal strength and knowledge of tower locations to pinpoint your location within a half km or so.  Wifi isn't needed for network location, it just helps make it more accurate.